# SQL Summing feature form multiple overtime rates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So at work currently the overtime is figured out in excel by hand, I wish to change this and use sql and ssrs to remove this manual task once a month. A slight problem i have is the complex overtime rates listed below.

(Overtime is once you have hit 40+ hours monday-friday, weekends and bank holidays are overtime no matter what)

```
                Mon-Fri            Sat                 Sun-BH            Rate
    NOH         6am-6pm           N/A                   N/A               x1
    OOH1        6pm - 00          8am - 00             8am- 00            x1.25
    OOh2        00- 6am           00-8am               00-8am             x1.25
```

Currently i have data in an sql table that is pulled from Toggl,

These rows are made up of a single input for the days tasks, made up of task, description, start date, start time, end date, end time and then duration.

Hopefully this will be enough for someone to help us out! The different rates really have thrown up some problems!

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[JSC010_Tech_Time](
[ID] [int] NULL,
[TECH] [varchar](100) NULL,
[EMAIL] [varchar](150) NULL,
[CLIENT] [varchar](50) NULL,
[PROJECT] [varchar](50) NULL,
[TASK] [varchar](50) NULL,
[DESCRIPTION] [varchar](250) NULL,
[BILLABLE] [varchar](3) NULL,
[START_DATE] [date] NULL,
[START_TIME] [time](7) NULL,
[END_DATE] [date] NULL,
[END_TIME] [time](7) NULL,
[DURATION] [time](7) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[JSC010_Tech_Time]
       ([ID]
       ,[TECH]
       ,[EMAIL]
       ,[CLIENT]
       ,[PROJECT]
       ,[TASK]
       ,[DESCRIPTION]
       ,[BILLABLE]
       ,[START_DATE]
       ,[START_TIME]
       ,[END_DATE]
       ,[END_TIME]
       ,[DURATION])
 VALUES
       (<ID, int,>
       ,<TECH, varchar(100),>
       ,<EMAIL, varchar(150),>
       ,<CLIENT, varchar(50),>
       ,<PROJECT, varchar(50),>
       ,<TASK, varchar(50),>
       ,<DESCRIPTION, varchar(250),>
       ,<BILLABLE, varchar(3),>
       ,<START_DATE, date,>
       ,<START_TIME, time(7),>
       ,<END_DATE, date,>
       ,<END_TIME, time(7),>
       ,<DURATION, time(7),>)
```

Here is some results below, which shows the user has worked over 40 hours (task of travel is not included in the weekly 40 hrs)

```
  insert into JSC010_Tech_Time values('10','bob','bob@bob.com','ABC','Work Order','Office','First Day, Induction along with manual handling certs','No','2019-04-01','09:00:00.0000000','2019-04-01','17:00:00.0000000','08:00:00.0000000')
  insert into JSC010_Tech_Time values('20','bob','bob@bob.com','ABC','Work Order','Office','2nd Day induction rack intro etc','No','2019-04-02','09:00:00.0000000','2019-04-02','17:00:00.0000000','08:00:00.0000000')
   insert into JSC010_Tech_Time values('30','bob','bob@bob.com','ABC','Work Order','Travel','office to site','Yes','2019-04-03','06:00:00.0000000','2019-04-03','08:00:00.0000000','02:00:00.0000000')
    insert into JSC010_Tech_Time values('40','bob','bob@bob.com','ABC','Work Order','Pre-patch','Work Order','Yes','2019-04-03','08:00:00.0000000','2019-04-03','16:00:00.0000000','08:00:00.0000000')
    insert into JSC010_Tech_Time values('50','bob','bob@bob.com','ABC','Work Order','Travel','site to office','Yes','2019-04-03','16:00:00.0000000','2019-04-03','18:00:00.0000000','02:00:00.0000000')
    insert into JSC010_Tech_Time values('60','bob','bob@bob.com','ABC','Work Order','Travel','site to office','Yes','2019-04-04','06:00:00.0000000','2019-04-04','08:00:00.0000000','02:00:00.0000000')
    insert into JSC010_Tech_Time values('70','bob','bob@bob.com','ABC','Work Order','Pre-patch','Work Order','Yes','2019-04-04','08:00:00.0000000','2019-04-04','14:00:00.0000000','06:00:00.0000000')
    insert into JSC010_Tech_Time values('80','bob','bob@bob.com','ABC','Work Order','Travel','work order','Yes','2019-04-04','14:00:00.0000000','2019-04-04','14:30:00.0000000','00:30:00.0000000')
     insert into JSC010_Tech_Time values('90','bob','bob@bob.com','ABC','Work Order','Audit','Work Order','Yes','2019-04-04','14:30:00.0000000','2019-04-04','16:30:00.0000000','02:00:00.0000000')
     insert into JSC010_Tech_Time values('100','bob','bob@bob.com','ABC','Work Order','Travel','Site-office','Yes','2019-04-04','16:30:00.0000000','2019-04-04','18:30:00.0000000','02:00:00.0000000')
    insert into JSC010_Tech_Time values('110','bob','bob@bob.com','ABC','Work Order','Travel','office-site','Yes','2019-04-05','05:00:00.0000000','2019-04-05','07:00:00.0000000','02:00:00.0000000')
    insert into JSC010_Tech_Time values('120','bob','bob@bob.com','ABC','Work Order','Audit','Work Order','Yes','2019-04-05','07:00:00.0000000','2019-04-05','19:00:00.0000000','12:00:00.0000000')
    insert into JSC010_Tech_Time values('130','bob','bob@bob.com','ABC','Work Order','Travel','Site-office','Yes','2019-04-05','19:30:00.0000000','2019-04-05','21:00:00.0000000','01:30:00.0000000')
```

So this should bring back results of

OOh1 :  1 hours
NOH  :  3 hours

This is because week total is 44 hrs, 05/4 is where an extra 4 hours is done, 3 before the 6pm deadline, 1 after.

Here is the bank holiday table.

```
     Create table JSC015_Bank_Holidays(ID int, Date date, day_Name varchar(10), Name varchar(30), Day int, Month int, Year int)
     Insert into JSC015_Bank_Holidays (ID,Date,day_Name, Name, Day, Month, Year) values (1,'20190826','Monday','Summer Bank Holiday','26','8','2019')
     Insert into JSC015_Bank_Holidays (ID,Date,day_Name, Name, Day, Month, Year) values (2,'20191225','Wednesday','Christmas Day','25','12','2019')
     Insert into JSC015_Bank_Holidays (ID,Date,day_Name, Name, Day, Month, Year) values (3,'20191226','Thursday','Boxing Day','26','12','2019')
     Insert into JSC015_Bank_Holidays (ID,Date,day_Name, Name, Day, Month, Year) values (4,'20200101','Wednesday','New Years Day','1','1','2020')
     Insert into JSC015_Bank_Holidays (ID,Date,day_Name, Name, Day, Month, Year) values (5,'20200410','Friday','Good Friday','10','4','2020')
     Insert into JSC015_Bank_Holidays (ID,Date,day_Name, Name, Day, Month, Year) values (6,'20200413','Monday','Easter Monday','13','4','2020')
     Insert into JSC015_Bank_Holidays (ID,Date,day_Name, Name, Day, Month, Year) values (7,'20200504','Monday','Early May Bank Holiday','4','5','2020')
     Insert into JSC015_Bank_Holidays (ID,Date,day_Name, Name, Day, Month, Year) values (8,'20200525','Monday','Spring Bank Holiday','25','5','2020')
     Insert into JSC015_Bank_Holidays (ID,Date,day_Name, Name, Day, Month, Year) values (9,'20200831','Monday','Summer Bank Holiday','31','8','2020')
     Insert into JSC015_Bank_Holidays (ID,Date,day_Name, Name, Day, Month, Year) values (10,'20201225','Friday','Christmas Day','25','12','2020')
     Insert into JSC015_Bank_Holidays (ID,Date,day_Name, Name, Day, Month, Year) values (11,'20201228','Monday','Boxing Day (Sub)','28','12','2020')

     select * from JSC015_Bank_Holidays
```

Comment: Can you provide your table definition and some sample rows (As a CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements), and the expected results for that date?

Comment: Hi Shawn, have placed in above. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: When someone asks for a script, that is what you should supply. You provided a skeleton insert statement and skipped the hard work of converting your "table" sample into insert statements. Somone might take pity and attempt it - but you would encourage others to help by doing it yourself. In addition, you don't provide any constraints in your ddl - most importantly the primary and natural keys. I'm also not certain what the column "Gro" with the value "Detail" means and how it relates to your table. ID is always 1 - seems suspicious as well.

Comment: Where is your table of Bank Holidays?

Comment: Sorry SMor, first post. The column Gro, is for conditional formatting in ssrs. ID 1 Is just me putting test data together for the example. I'll make a bunch of insert statements and upload tonight. Literally is just a rough start, only got given the project Friday.

Comment: Habo, cheers for the response I will upload tonight.

Comment: Hi All, have added the bank holiday data, insert statements for all. Cheers for any help

Answer (score 1):

I've re-written the query to make it simpler. This pivots the data on the rate type and sums the individual hours throughout the result set, taking in to account the duration (whether or not this is rounded to a whole hour) and where in the hour the shift starts/ends (in combination with the duration can be used to determine which hour to round down to the nearest minute value).

### EDIT:

I have modified the query to be able to handle time periods which are less than an hour long.

### 2nd Edit:

I have modified the query to handle the first and last hours independently so it should calculate the number of minutes correctly depending on if the first or last hour should be considered.

### 3rd Edit:

I've fixed the rounding issue, it was to do with the way that the minutes land.

I've also added 3 commented sections in to the query to help you with debugging (in case you want to have a go at fixing some of these issues too).

The commented out where clause will allow you to focus on which row is causing you the issue

The commented "houroftheday" column (commented out of the select statement and the inner select statement) will allow you to see what value is being calculated per hour.

### 4th Edit:

I have re-written the query to work in a slightly different way. 
To account for shifts which span more than one calendar day (cross midnight) I've used a common table expression which assigns a unique id per hour throughout the week. This prevents the issue we were having with your last comment where the starting hour of the shift was 19 and the finishing hour was 2. This common table expression may need to be expanded to cover shifts that stretch over calendar weeks.

```
/*Create the temp table for the sample rates data*/
CREATE TABLE #JSC010_Tech_Time(
[ID] [int] NULL,
[TECH] [varchar](100) NULL,
[EMAIL] [varchar](150) NULL,
[CLIENT] [varchar](50) NULL,
[PROJECT] [varchar](50) NULL,
[TASK] [varchar](50) NULL,
[DESCRIPTION] [varchar](250) NULL,
[BILLABLE] [varchar](3) NULL,
[START_DATE] [date] NULL,
[START_TIME] [time](7) NULL,
[END_DATE] [date] NULL,
[END_TIME] [time](7) NULL,
[DURATION] [time](7) NULL
);

/*insert the sample data modified to fit table structure provided*/
INSERT INTO #JSC010_Tech_Time
       ([ID]
       ,[TECH]
       ,[EMAIL]
       ,[CLIENT]
       ,[PROJECT]
       ,[TASK]
       ,[DESCRIPTION]
       ,[BILLABLE]
       ,[START_DATE]
       ,[START_TIME]
       ,[END_DATE]
       ,[END_TIME]
       ,[DURATION])
 VALUES
(1,   'Bob', 'Bob@bob.com', 'ABC', 'Accounts', '',    'Office  First Day, Induction along with manual handling certs',   'No',  '2019-04-01',  '09:00:00.0000000',    '2019-04-01', '17:00:00.0000000',    '08:00:00.0000000'),
(2,   'Bob', 'Bob@bob.com', 'ABC', 'Accounts', '',  'Office  2nd Day induction rack intro etc',    'No',  '2019-04-02',  '09:00:00.0000000',    '2019-04-02',  '17:00:00.0000000',    '08:00:00.0000000'),
(3,   'Bob', 'Bob@bob.com', 'ABC', 'Accounts', '',   'Travel  office to site',  'Yes', '2019-04-03',  '06:00:00.0000000',    '2019-04-03',  '08:00:00.0000000',    '02:00:00.0000000'),
(4,   'Bob', 'Bob@bob.com', 'ABC', 'Accounts', '',   'Pre-patch   Work Order',  'Yes', '2019-04-03',  '08:00:00.0000000',    '2019-04-03',  '16:00:00.0000000',    '08:00:00.0000000'),
(5,   'Bob', 'Bob@bob.com', 'ABC', 'Accounts', '',   'Travel  site to office',  'Yes', '2019-04-03',  '16:00:00.0000000',    '2019-04-03',  '18:00:00.0000000',    '02:00:00.0000000'),
(6,   'Bob', 'Bob@bob.com', 'ABC', 'Accounts', '',   'Travel  site to office',  'Yes', '2019-04-04',  '06:00:00.0000000',    '2019-04-04',  '08:00:00.0000000',    '02:00:00.0000000'),
(7,   'Bob', 'Bob@bob.com', 'ABC', 'Accounts', '',   'Pre-patch   Work Order',  'Yes', '2019-04-04',  '08:00:00.0000000',    '2019-04-04',  '14:00:00.0000000',    '06:00:00.0000000'),
(8,   'Bob', 'Bob@bob.com', 'ABC', 'Accounts', '',   'Travel  Journey', 'Yes', '2019-04-04',  '14:00:00.0000000',    '2019-04-04',  '14:30:00.0000000',    '00:30:00.0000000'),
(9,   'Bob', 'Bob@bob.com', 'ABC', 'Accounts', '',   'Audit   Work Order',  'Yes', '2019-04-04',  '14:30:00.0000000',    '2019-04-04',  '16:30:00.0000000',    '02:00:00.0000000'),
(10,   'Bob', 'Bob@bob.com', 'ABC', 'Accounts','',    'Travel  Site-office', 'Yes', '2019-04-04',  '16:30:00.0000000',    '2019-04-04',  '18:30:00.0000000',    '02:00:00.0000000'),
(11,   'Bob', 'Bob@bob.com', 'ABC', 'Accounts','',    'Travel  office-site', 'Yes', '2019-04-05',  '05:00:00.0000000',    '2019-04-05',  '07:00:00.0000000',    '02:00:00.0000000'),
(12,   'Bob', 'Bob@bob.com', 'ABC', 'Accounts','',    'Audit   Work Order',  'Yes', '2019-04-05',  '07:00:00.0000000',    '2019-04-05',  '19:00:00.0000000',    '12:00:00.0000000'),
(13,   'Bob', 'Bob@bob.com', 'ABC', 'Accounts','',    'Travel  Site-office', 'Yes', '2019-04-05',  '19:30:00.0000000',    '2019-04-05',  '21:00:00.0000000',    '01:30:00.0000000');

INSERT INTO #JSC010_Tech_Time ([ID],[TECH],[EMAIL],[CLIENT],[PROJECT],[TASK],[DESCRIPTION],[BILLABLE],[START_DATE],[START_TIME],[END_DATE],[END_TIME],[DURATION])
VALUES ((select isnull(max(ID),0)+1 from #JSC010_Tech_Time),'bob','bob@bob.com','project B','Bob Project 04/05/2019','End to End ','overtime ','Yes','20190504','05:00:00','20190504','18:00:00','13:00:00');

 INSERT INTO #JSC010_Tech_Time ([ID],[TECH],[EMAIL],[CLIENT],[PROJECT],[TASK],[DESCRIPTION],[BILLABLE],[START_DATE],[START_TIME],[END_DATE],[END_TIME],[DURATION])
 VALUES ((select isnull(max(ID),0)+1 from #JSC010_Tech_Time),'BOB','BOB','BOB','Q19 Migration','patch','wo','Yes','20190418','08:00:57','20190418','12:30:57','04:30:00');

 INSERT INTO #JSC010_Tech_Time ([ID],[TECH],[EMAIL],[CLIENT],[PROJECT],[TASK],[DESCRIPTION],[BILLABLE],[START_DATE],[START_TIME],[END_DATE],[END_TIME],[DURATION])
 VALUES ((select isnull(max(ID),0)+1 from #jsc010_tech_time),'bob','bob.com','Projects','Q18','Travel','city','Yes','20190404','14:00:00','20190404','14:30:00','00:30:00');

 INSERT INTO #JSC010_Tech_Time ([ID],[TECH],[EMAIL],[CLIENT],[PROJECT],[TASK],[DESCRIPTION],[BILLABLE],[START_DATE],[START_TIME],[END_DATE],[END_TIME],[DURATION])
 VALUES ((select isnull(max(ID),0)+1 from #JSC010_Tech_Time),'bob','bob.com','DACC','140-2','Travel','Between site','Yes','20190409','01:00:00','20190409','01:15:00','00:15:00');

 INSERT INTO #JSC010_Tech_Time ([ID],[TECH],[EMAIL],[CLIENT],[PROJECT],[TASK],[DESCRIPTION],[BILLABLE],[START_DATE],[START_TIME],[END_DATE],[END_TIME],[DURATION])
 VALUES ((select isnull(max(ID),0)+1 from #JSC010_Tech_Time),'Bob','bob.com','T','DRC','Engineer On Site','','Yes','20190509','18:30:00','20190509','19:15:00','00:45:00');

 INSERT INTO #JSC010_Tech_Time ([ID],[TECH],[EMAIL],[CLIENT],[PROJECT],[TASK],[DESCRIPTION],[BILLABLE],[START_DATE],[START_TIME],[END_DATE],[END_TIME],[DURATION])
 VALUES ((select isnull(max(ID),0)+1 from #JSC010_Tech_Time),'Bob','bob.com','DACC','TH-BS','Decom','Decom BS','Yes','20190409','13:15:00','20190409','15:30:00','02:15:00');

 INSERT INTO #JSC010_Tech_Time ([ID],[TECH],[EMAIL],[CLIENT],[PROJECT],[TASK],[DESCRIPTION],[BILLABLE],[START_DATE],[START_TIME],[END_DATE],[END_TIME],[DURATION])
 VALUES ((select isnull(max(ID),0)+1 from #JSC010_Tech_Time),'bob','bob.com','BAU','BloombergWK','Engineer On Site','','Yes','20190522','22:45:39','20190522','23:30:52','00:45:13');

 INSERT INTO #JSC010_Tech_Time ([ID],[TECH],[EMAIL],[CLIENT],[PROJECT],[TASK],[DESCRIPTION],[BILLABLE],[START_DATE],[START_TIME],[END_DATE],[END_TIME],[DURATION])
 VALUES ((select isnull(max(ID),0)+1 from #JSC010_Tech_Time),'bob','bob.com','DCC','140-','Decom','Decom','Yes','20190409','08:45:00','20190409','13:00:00','04:15:00');

 INSERT INTO #JSC010_Tech_Time ([ID],[TECH],[EMAIL],[CLIENT],[PROJECT],[TASK],[DESCRIPTION],[BILLABLE],[START_DATE],[START_TIME],[END_DATE],[END_TIME],[DURATION])
 VALUES ((select isnull(max(ID),0)+1 from #JSC010_Tech_Time),'Bob','BOB.com','Projects','LD6 - 01/05/2019','Patch','devices','Yes','20190501','19:00:00','20190502','02:00:00','07:00:00');

/*build rates table*/
declare @ratesperday table (
    rateperdayid int identity(1,1) primary key,
    weekdayno int,
    hourno int,
    ratetype nvarchar(5),
    rate FLOAT
);
/*use incrementing values to build relevant week day numbers and hour numbers*/
declare @dayno int = 1;
declare @hourno int=0;
/*loop through each day and perform logic per hour starting at midnight (0)*/
while @dayno < = 7
    begin
    select @hourno=0;
       /*loop through from midnight until 11 pm per day*/
        while @hourno<=23
            begin
 --              Mon-Fri            Sat                 Sun-BH            Rate
    --NOH         6am-6pm           N/A                   N/A               x1
    --OOH1        6pm - 00          8am - 00             8am- 00            x1.25
    --OOh2        00- 6am           00-8am               00-8am             x1.25
            insert @ratesperday (weekdayno, hourno, ratetype)
            select @dayno, @hourno, case when @dayno in (1, 7) and @hourno >=0 and @hourno <8 then 'OOH2'
                                         when @dayno in (1, 7) and @hourno>=8 and @hourno <= 23 then 'OOH1'
                                         when @dayno in (2, 3, 4, 5, 6) and @hourno >=0 and @hourno <6 then 'OOH2'
                                         when @dayno in (2, 3, 4, 5, 6) and @hourno >18 and @hourno <= 23 then 'OOH1'
                                         else 'NOH' end;
            select @hourno=@hourno+1;
            end
    select @dayno=@dayno+1;

    end
    /*use the applied rate type to set the rate in one hit*/
    update @ratesperday set rate=case ratetype when 'NOH' then 1 else 1.25 end;
with dayjoin as (
    select id, datepart(weekday,start_date) as wekkdaystart, datepart(hour, start_time) as weekhourstart, 
               datepart(weekday, end_date) as weekdayend, datepart(hour,end_time) as weekhourend,
               min(rateperdayid) as starthourid, max(rateperdayid) as endhourid from #JSC010_Tech_Time j inner join @ratesperday 
               r on (datepart(weekday, start_date)=r.weekdayno and datepart(hour, START_TIME)=r.hourno)
                 or (datepart(weekday, END_DATE)=r.weekdayno and datepart(hour, END_TIME)=r.hourno)
    group by  id, datepart(weekday,start_date), datepart(hour, start_time), datepart(weekday, end_date), datepart(hour,end_time))

--/*As the overtime rate types are known then they can be pivoted directly. The logic on the source derived table (src) manipulates the data which row by row checks the rate type per hour and also checks if that hour is a whole hour or a sub-set.*/
    select id, tech, email, client, project, task, description, billable, start_date, start_time, end_date, end_time, duration, --weekdayno, houroftheday,
    --rateperdayid, 
    [NOH], [OOH1], [OOH2] from
    (
    select j.ID, tech, email, client, project, task, description, billable, start_date, start_time, end_date, end_time, duration,
    --weekdayno, 
    --hourno AS houroftheday, rateperdayid,
                       case when datepart(minute,START_TIME)>0 and hourno=datepart(hour, start_time) and hourno=DATEPART(hour, j.end_time) and datepart(minute, duration)=0 then coalesce(cast(datepart(minute,duration)as float)/60, 0)
                            when datepart(minute,end_time)>0 and hourno=datepart(hour, end_time)-1 and datepart(minute, duration)>0 and DATEPART(hour, duration)=0 then coalesce(cast(datepart(minute,duration) as float)/60, 0)
                            when DATEPART(hour, duration)=0 and hourno = datepart(hour, START_TIME) and  hourno = DATEPART(hour, end_time) then coalesce(cast(datepart(minute,duration) as float)/60, 0)
                            when hourno=DATEPART(hour, end_time) and DATEPART(hour, duration)>0 and DATEPART(minute, end_time)>DATEPART(minute, start_time) and DATEPART(minute, start_time)=0 then coalesce(cast(datepart(minute,duration) as float)/60, 0)
                            when hourno=DATEPART(hour, start_time) and DATEPART(minute, duration)>0 and DATEPART(minute, start_time)=DATEPART(minute, duration) then coalesce(cast(datepart(minute,duration) as float)/60, 0)
                            when hourno = DATEPART(hour, start_time) and 60-DATEPART(minute, start_time)=DATEPART(minute, duration) then coalesce(cast(datepart(minute,duration) as float)/60, 0)
                            else cast(1 as float) end as hourno, ratetype 
    from #JSC010_Tech_Time j inner join
    dayjoin d on datepart(weekday, j.start_date)=d.wekkdaystart and datepart(weekday, j.end_date)=d.weekdayend
             and datepart(hour, j.start_time)=d.weekhourstart and datepart(hour, j.end_time)=d.weekhourend
             and d.id=j.ID
    inner join @ratesperday r on r.rateperdayid between d.starthourid and case 
    when DATEPART(hour, duration)=0 and datepart(hour, j.start_time)=datepart(hour, j.end_time) then d.endhourid
    when datepart(minute, j.end_time)>0 and datepart(minute, j.start_time)<>datepart(minute, j.end_time) and datepart(hour, duration)>0 then D.endhourid 
    else d.endhourid-1 end
    --where j.ID in (22)
    ) src
    pivot
    (sum(hourno) for ratetype in ([NOH], [OOH1], [OOH2])) piv

/*drop table to re-use in query batch for development purposes*/
drop table #JSC010_Tech_Time;
```

#### Result Set:

[image]

Comment: Tip: `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, SampleDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`.

Comment: Thank you @HABO I had not considered that.

Comment: This is fantastic Dwight, im just giving it a try on the true data now to see what it returns, sorry for the slow response! Imagine ill have a few more questions!  Thanks again!

Comment: Regards to the grouping it would be by week, due to the first 40 hours not being affected by the rates table and are contracted hours. But I'll be able to figure that out! Many thanks for your work!

Comment: No problem at all. If this answer or any other has helped to point you in the right direction, please show your appreciation by up-voting that answer :).

Comment: I certainly will! Have had a real good crack and have got it doing nearly exactly what i need. just a few duplicate results and i can't work out why! This for instance brings back 20 hours, over ooh1 and ooh2 10 in each? INSERT INTO [dbo].[JSC010_Tech_Time] ([ID],[TECH],[EMAIL],[CLIENT],[PROJECT],[TASK],[DESCRIPTION],[BILLABLE],[START_DATE],[START_TIME],[END_DATE],[END_TIME],[DURATION])VALUES ((select isnull(max(ID),0)+1 from jsc010_tech_time),'bob','bob@bob.com','project B','Bob Project 04/05/2019','End to End ','overtime ','Yes','20190504','05:00:00','20190504','18:00:00','13:00:00')

Comment: I've diagnosed the problem, the query is assuming that all employee records will have some NOH rated time. This record does not so the query is exhibiting odd behaviour. I'll re-work the query so that it copes better with this scenario.

Comment: Please see the updated answer, let me know if you run in to any issues with it :).

Comment: Such a quick fix!  Thanks so much, this version i understood alot more! One hopefully last thing i hvae noticed, every now and again records are coming back with say 30 minutes difference to what they should be. This for instance INSERT INTO [dbo].[JSC010_Tech_Time] ([ID],[TECH],[EMAIL],[CLIENT],[PROJECT],[TASK],[DESCRIPTION],[BILLABLE],[START_DATE],[START_TIME],[END_DATE],[END_TIME],[DURATION])VALUES ((select isnull(max(ID),0)+1 from jsc010_tech_time),'BOB','BOB','BOB','Q19 Migration','patch','wo','Yes','20190418','08:00:57','20190418','12:30:57','04:30:00')
any ideas?

Comment: This is an interesting bug to do with how the start and the end of the shift are treated. I'll work on something and edit my answer later on (please ignore the first edit I made a moment or so ago).

Comment: Please see updated query. The issue arose from a bug in the joining condition which was correctly taking an hour off to prevent calculating the final hour of a shift as an hours work. But for shifts which end part way through the hour was not correctly including part of that hour.

Comment: Brilliant, that solved that one! Have just noticed that these are now pulling through 1 hour even if they are only 30 minutes? INSERT INTO [dbo].[JSC010_Tech_Time] ([ID],[TECH],[EMAIL],[CLIENT],[PROJECT],[TASK],[DESCRIPTION],[BILLABLE],[START_DATE],[START_TIME],[END_DATE],[END_TIME],[DURATION])VALUES ((select isnull(max(ID),0)+1 from jsc010_tech_time),'bob','bob.com','Projects','Q18','Travel','city','Yes','20190404','14:00:00','20190404','14:30:00','00:30:00')

Comment: INSERT INTO [dbo].[JSC010_Tech_Time] ([ID],[TECH],[EMAIL],[CLIENT],[PROJECT],[TASK],[DESCRIPTION],[BILLABLE],[START_DATE],[START_TIME],[END_DATE],[END_TIME],[DURATION])VALUES ((select isnull(max(ID),0)+1 from jsc010_tech_time),'bob','bob.com','DACC','140-2','Travel','Between site','Yes','20190409','01:00:00','20190409','01:15:00','00:15:00')

Comment: Please see updated answer. The problem arose because the query was relying on all rows lasting more than an hour. There may still be some permutations to work on however I feel we are almost there. Let me know if you have any further issues.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help so far! Last two i promise! INSERT INTO [dbo].[JSC010_Tech_Time] ([ID],[TECH],[EMAIL],[CLIENT],[PROJECT],[TASK],[DESCRIPTION],[BILLABLE],[START_DATE],[START_TIME],[END_DATE],[END_TIME],[DURATION])VALUES ((select isnull(max(ID),0)+1 from jsc010_tech_time),'Bob','bob.com','T','DRC','Engineer On Site','','Yes','20190509','18:30:00','20190509','19:15:00','00:45:00') is bringing back 0.75 in NOH correct, and 1 hour in OOh1?

Comment: INSERT INTO [dbo].[JSC010_Tech_Time] ([ID],[TECH],[EMAIL],[CLIENT],[PROJECT],[TASK],[DESCRIPTION],[BILLABLE],[START_DATE],[START_TIME],[END_DATE],[END_TIME],[DURATION])VALUES ((select isnull(max(ID),0)+1 from jsc010_tech_time),'Bob','bob.com','DACC','TH-BS','Decom','Decom BS','Yes','20190409','13:15:00','20190409','15:30:00','02:15:00') is coming back as 0.5 hours in NOH rather than 2.25

Comment: INSERT INTO [dbo].[JSC010_Tech_Time] ([ID],[TECH],[EMAIL],[CLIENT],[PROJECT],[TASK],[DESCRIPTION],[BILLABLE],[START_DATE],[START_TIME],[END_DATE],[END_TIME],[DURATION])VALUES ((select isnull(max(ID),0)+1 from jsc010_tech_time),'bob','bob.com','BAU','BloombergWK','Engineer On Site','','Yes','20190522','22:45:39','20190522','23:30:52','00:45:13')

Comment: Please see updated answer. There was an issue with the first and last hour being treated for the number of minutes, now the query is better able to handle whether or not the first or last hour should be treated for the number of minutes.

Comment: Now seem to have a rounding up issue! 
INSERT INTO [dbo].[JSC010_Tech_Time] ([ID],[TECH],[EMAIL],[CLIENT],[PROJECT],[TASK],[DESCRIPTION],[BILLABLE],[START_DATE],[START_TIME],[END_DATE],[END_TIME],[DURATION])VALUES ((select isnull(max(ID),0)+1 from jsc010_tech_time),'bob','bob.com','DCC','140-','Decom','Decom','Yes','20190409','08:45:00','20190409','13:00:00','04:15:00')

Comment: Thanks for this, have found a few more bits but seem to have sussed it out! Only one major thing i have noticed and can't figure out is a job that starts say monday evening, and finishes tuesday morning doesnt return? Its to do with the inner join first statement, but not sure how to adapt it?

Comment: INSERT INTO [dbo].[JSC010_Tech_Time] ([ID],[TECH],[EMAIL],[CLIENT],[PROJECT],[TASK],[DESCRIPTION],[BILLABLE],[START_DATE],[START_TIME],[END_DATE],[END_TIME],[DURATION])VALUES ((select isnull(max(ID),0)+1 from jsc010_tech_time),'Bob','BOB.com','Projects','LD6 - 01/05/2019','Patch','devices','Yes','20190501','19:00:00','20190502','02:00:00','07:00:00')

Comment: Please see updated answer which uses a different method to calculate the number of hours worked.

Comment: You're very welcome :) it's been a long road! If this answer or any other has helped to point you in the right direction, please show your appreciation with an up-vote and/or an accept.